# What is fastest way to find number of matches between arrays?

Tags: c#, optimization, arrays, match

Currently, I am testing every integer element against each other to find which ones match.  The arrays do not contain duplicates within their own set. Also, the arrays are not always equal lengths. Are there any tricks to speed this up?  I am doing this thousands of times, so it's starting to become a bottle neck in my program, which is in C#.

Comment: Is it that you simply want a unique list of all integers that exist in both arrays?

Comment: To add to Thomas's comment, are the arrays ordered?

Comment: That would be another way of putting it.  A unique list common in both sets.  Yes, they are ordered.

Comment: Are there any limits on the number of items or on the range of the integers that we could take advantage of?

Answer (score 6):

You could use LINQ:

```
var query = firstArray.Intersect(secondArray);
```

Or if the arrays are already sorted you could iterate over the two arrays yourself:

```
int[] a = { 1, 3, 5 };
int[] b = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<int> result = new List<int>();
int ia = 0;
int ib = 0;
while (ia < a.Length && ib < b.Length)
{
    if (a[ia] == b[ib])
    {
        result.Add(a[ia]);
        ib++;
        ia++;
    }
    else if (a[ia] < b[ib])
    {
        ia++;
    }
    else
    {
        ib++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark: your code silently supposes that the arrays are sorted

Comment: John already stated that the arrays are ordered in comments above.

Answer (score 5):

Use a HashSet

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(firstArray);
set.IntersectWith(secondArray);
```

The set now contains only the values that exist in both arrays.

Comment: I think you want .Intersect rather than .Union

Comment: Just tried the HashSet with IntersectWith and it's twice as slow compared to iterating over all elements.

Answer (score 0):

If such a comparison is a bottleneck in your program, you are perhaps using an inappropriate data structure. The simplest way might be to keep your data sorted. Then for finding out the common entries, you would need to traverse both arrays only once. Another option would be to keep the data in a HashSet.